# How to bind array to list when array is property of the object

Tags: sapui5

I have the following object:

```
parent = {
    prop1: "asd",
    prop2: "zxc",
    arr: [
        { 
          title: "qwe", 
          attr: {attr1: "987", attr2: "dfg"}
        },
        { 
          title: "poi",
          attr: {attr1: "345", attr2: "jkl"}
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to bind it to the following list:

```
<List id="list" items="{parent>/arr}" headerText="Example">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="{parent>arr/title}" type="Active" press="onListItemPress">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute text="{parent>arr/attr/attr2}" />
            </attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

I just cannot make it work.

What is the right way to show the **title** and the **attr2** properties in this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this syntax view binding below it's works :

```
 <List id="list" items="{parent>/arr}" headerText="Example">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="{parent>title}" type="Active" press="onListItemPress">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute text="{parent>attr/attr2}" />
            </attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```